# How to I implement this C++ structure code in Python?

Tags: python, c++, python-3.x

so I've found the following snippet of C++ code online and I wanted to make something equivalent to it in Python. The C++ snippet is:

```
struct EmployeePayout{
    uint64_t    base_payout;
    uint64_t    initial_salary: 14;
    uint64_t    maximum_salary : 14;
    uint64_t    yearly_bonus : 30;
    uint64_t    monthly_bonus : 6;
};
```

The portion that I'm unfamiliar with and have never seen before is the portion with the `: 14` or the `: number` in general. What exactly does that part do?

I've written a portion of the above code in Python using classes. The code portion is:

```
class EmployeePayout:
    def __init__(self, base_payout, init_sal, max_sal, y_bonus, m_bonus):
        self.base_payout = base_payout
        self.initial_salary = init_sal
        self.max_salary = max_sal
        self.yearly_bonus = y_bonus
        self.monthly_bonus = m_bonus

        self.adjust_values()

    def adjust_values(self):
        #The logic here
        pass
```

where I've made the method `adjust_values()` mainly for the purpose of handling the part with the `: number`. How would I go about implementing this `adjust_values()` method?

Comment: It's the width or size of the field in bits. It does not really make sense to translate a c++ struct directly to a Python class, especially anything regarding field sizes, as python stores instance variables in a dictionary (hash map) and offers little for specifying field sizes.

Comment: This is a packed bitfield. A somewhat archaic language feature inherited from C; but useful when hacking low-level hardware device driver code. Not something that Python code would really care about; and if this is really used for something, in C++, it's going to be a struggle for Python to replicate.

Comment: You would need to use the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#module-struct) module to better emulate the memory layout of  C/C++ structure with [bit fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field) in it like that.